# Camel 3.2 PahoEndpointBuilder not working

Tags: apache-camel

I try to use the PahoEndpointBuilder

```
    PahoEndpointBuilder endpoint = paho (topic).brokerUrl (brokerUrl);
```

but starting the route based on that endpoint always leads to an exception.

```
Caused by: org.apache.camel.ResolveEndpointFailedException: Failed to resolve endpoint: paho:myTestTopicMandant9?brokerUrl=tcp%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A1883 due to: There are 1 parameters that couldn't be set on the endpoint. Check the uri if the parameters are spelt correctly and that they are properties of the endpoint. Unknown parameters=[{brokerUrl=tcp://localhost:1883}]
    at org.apache.camel.support.DefaultComponent.validateParameters(DefaultComponent.java:351)
    at org.apache.camel.support.DefaultComponent.createEndpoint(DefaultComponent.java:169)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.AbstractCamelContext.doGetEndpoint(AbstractCamelContext.java:952)
```

Is this a bug?

Answer (score 0):

Its a bug in Camel 3.2 that has been logged in JIRA: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-14921